# How can I run a Python desktop app in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, linux, windows, virtualenv

I want to run a Python3 app by clicking on an icon on the desktop and activate a specific virtualenv for it on Linux and Windows.

How can I do this?

Edit: Maybe the question is a bit misleading. I have to activate the venv first and then I have to run the app in this venv

Comment: isn't this only using exact path to your python venv and python file? `/path-to-your-venv/Scripts/python your_python_program.py`

Comment: No, you have to activate the venv first and then run the app in this venv

Comment: In many cases activating the virtual environment is not necessary and @rizquuula suggestion should work. If it does not work, then you might need to write a script (shell on unix or batch on windows) that does the activation then runs the Python command (activation can also usually be done by simply setting the right environment variables) it is all quite straightforward and quite well documented.